# Colour a cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to color the particular cell in DataGridView. I tried to do but it doesn't work.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

but for whole column it works...

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

But i need a cell please if you can help Thanks

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;` works fine here. What is the celltype?

Comment: yes that should work, sounds like the CellStyle is set back somehow. Check your code, if you cant find where this happens you could add `DataGridView1_CellStyleChanged`  and set a breakpoint inside and debug it.

Comment: should be `dataGridView1_CellStyleContentChanged`... too late to edit.

Comment: `Style.BackColor = Color.Red` will change cell's backcolor of normal state. If cell is selected in the moment you want to change color, then use `Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle MakeItRed = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
MakeItRed.BackColor = Color.Red;

//make a whole column red
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle = MakeItRed;

//make a specific cell red
DataGridViewRow row2 = dataGridView1.Rows[2];
row2.Cells[2].Style = MakeItRed;

        }
```

Comment: It works but when there is too much data in dataGridView then program gets very slow because it runs on every cell. Is there any other way to do it?